# Objective-C call Swift function

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

Swift function defined in `MySwift.swift` File:

```
func SomeSwift()
{

}
```

`SomeSwift()` is not defined in any Swift class, it is just a pure function.

After <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to build the project, open `Project-Swift.h`, the `SomeSwift()` isn't show in there.

Does the function in Swift have to be defined in some Swift class? and with `@objc` marked?

like the following:

```
@objc class SomeSwift: NSObject {
   func SomeSwift()
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: Top-level functions are not supported: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35

Answer (score 7):

Referring to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) about Using Swift from Objective-C:

> A Swift class must be a descendant of an Objective-C class to be
>   accessible and usable in Objective-C

Means that your class should be `@objc class SomeSwift: NSObject` (You're right!), but you CANNOT access *the whole thing* in Swift file:

> When you create a Swift class that descends from an Objective-C class,
>   the class and its members—properties, methods, subscripts, and
>   initializers—that are compatible with Objective-C are automatically
>   available from Objective-C. This **excludes** Swift-only features, such as
>   those listed here:
>
> Generics
>
> Tuples
>
> Enumerations defined in Swift without Int raw value type
>
> Structures defined in Swift
>
> **Top-level functions defined in Swift**
>
> Global variables defined in Swift
>
> Typealiases defined in Swift
>
> Swift-style variadics
>
> Nested types
>
> Curried functions

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID53).

**So, you cannot use the `SomeSwift` top-level function.**

Even if you tried to add `@objc` before its declaration, the compiler will tell that:

[image]

> @objc can only used when with memebers of classes, @objc protocols,
>   and concrete extensions of classes.

with a suggestion to remove `@objc`.